# How do i rotate a rabbit leg without it looking funky?

Tags: modeling, rigging, armature, weight-painting

I modelled a rabbit and now i want it to be able to lie down. However right now the leg verticies twist crazily because of how the hindlegs are made up. Does anyone know how to properly model rabbit legs and can give me some tips ?

[image]

[image]

( PS: it's supposed to be a chocolate rabbit so it won't have fur to hide things.. maybe it will look more like a big brown frog with ears? (': )

Comment: you need to get some reference on how real-life rabbits move, the back legs shouldn't bend sideways like that https://duckduckgo.com/?q=rabbit+jump&iax=images&ia=images

Comment: If you look at many modeling tutorials, one consistent technique is that the fitting of skeleton to mesh is done in a "Rest" position: in essence where the limbs are well separated from the other body parts and not curled up.   This allows the Armature Parenting to better distribute the bone movement "weights" to each vertex in the mesh.  If you did your parenting of the silly wabbit with its legs curled up, this could be the cause of the bad twists in the mesh as its legs stretch out.

Comment: Cute little frog :D ... For a rabbit, the body is too short and the back legs are too long (https://agriculture.vic.gov.au/__data/assets/image/0017/651122/Rabbit1.jpeg)